# Erro ao adicionar numa List no JAVA

Tags: java, lista

Estou tentando adicionar um valor a uma lista mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Cannot invoke "java.util.List.add(Object)" because "[]" is null

O código é esse:

```
static void montaEl(int tam, Elemento el) {
    int i = 0;
    List <Elemento> elA[];   
    elA = new ArrayList[tam];
    elA[i].add(el);
    imprimePares(elA, 9); }
```

Comment: Ao usar `[]`, vc na verdade criou um array, no qual cada elemento é um `List`. Ao fazer `new ArrayList[tam]`, vc só disse que o array tem `tam` elementos, mas como os elementos ainda não estão inicializados, eles são `null`. E  ao fazer `elA[i]` vc tentou acessar um desses elementos `null`, por isso não foi possível acessar o método `add`, daí o erro. Se quer apenas uma lista, faça `List<Elemento> elA = new ArrayList<>()` e depois `elA.add(el)`

Comment: Entendi. Só que quando faço isso passo a ter outro problema. O método imprimePares não pode ser mudado, isso é imposto pelo professor, só que aí passa da dar outro erro "incompatible types: List<Elemento> cannot be converted to List<Elemento>[]". imprimePares foi passado assim: static void imprimePares(List<Elemento>vet[], int k). Se eu pudesse alterar, colocaria static void imprimePares(List<Elemento>vet, int k).

Comment: Nesse caso vc tem que inicializar cada posição do array com uma nova lista: `elA[i] = new ArrayList<>()` (na verdade, fazer um `for` para todas as posições do array, assim nenhuma lista fica nula)

Comment: Valeu. Vou fazer isso. Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar esse exemplo para chegar onde quer, na resolução do seu problema de add na lista:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListAddExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> vowels = new ArrayList<>();

        vowels.add("A"); // [A]
        vowels.add("E"); // [A, E]
        vowels.add("U"); // [A, E, U]

        System.out.println(vowels); // [A, E, U]

        vowels.add(2, "I"); // [A, E, I, U]
        vowels.add(3, "O"); // [A, E, I, O, U]

        System.out.println(vowels); // [A, E, I, O, U]
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Vou fazer isso.